# libcurl unable to properly download image file

Tags: c++, http, libcurl

I've created this very basic curl wrapper and I am able to download html pages with it, but the issue I have is when I try to get images (haven't tried other files).

```
class BasicCurlWrapper
{
    CURL* m_curlHandle{ nullptr };
    std::string m_current_url{};
    std::string m_destinationFilePath{};
    std::ofstream m_outputFile{};
    std::ios_base::openmode m_fileOpenMode{ std::ios::out };
    bool m_verbose{ false };

public:
    BasicCurlWrapper()
    {
        m_curlHandle = curl_easy_init();
    }

    ~BasicCurlWrapper()
    {
        curl_easy_cleanup(m_curlHandle);
        //curl_global_cleanup();
    }

    void downloadUrl(const std::string& url, const std::string& destination, std::ios_base::openmode openmode = std::ios::out) 
    {
        if (m_outputFile.is_open()) {
            m_outputFile.close();
        }

        m_current_url = url;
        m_destinationFilePath = destination;
        m_fileOpenMode = openmode;
        char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE] = { 0 };

        curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, url.data());        
        curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, m_verbose ? 1L : 0L); //Switch on full protocol/debug output while testing        
        curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L); //disable progress meter, set to 0L to enable it
        curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36");
        curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, BasicCurlWrapper::write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, this);
        curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
        //curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "");
        //curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "C:/msys64/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt");

        auto res = curl_easy_perform(m_curlHandle);

        if (m_outputFile.is_open()) {
            m_outputFile.close();
        }

        if (res == CURLE_OK) {
            std::cout << "Downloaded file\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "ERROR: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << '\n' << errbuf << '\n';
        }
    }


    void setVerbose(bool cond)
    {
        m_verbose = cond;
    }

    //https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2008-09/0250.html
    static std::size_t write_data(const char* ptr, const std::size_t size, const std::size_t nmemb, void* classIntance)
    {

        if (nmemb > 0) {
            static_cast<BasicCurlWrapper*>(classIntance)->writeToFile(ptr, nmemb);
        }
        return nmemb;
    }

private:

    void writeToFile(const char* ptr, const std::size_t nmemb)
    {
        if (!m_outputFile.is_open()) {
            m_outputFile.open(m_destinationFilePath, m_fileOpenMode);
        }        

        if (m_outputFile.is_open()) {
            std::cout << "Writing data amount: " << nmemb << '\n';
            m_outputFile.write(ptr, nmemb);
        } else {
            auto errorMsg{ std::string{"Unable to open file: " + m_destinationFilePath } };
            throw std::runtime_error{ errorMsg };
        }
    }
};
```

So I am using it like this:

```
 BasicCurlWrapper cr;
 cr.setVerbose(true);
 cr.downloadUrl("https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/google/noto-emoji-activities/512/52730-soccer-ball-icon.png", "ball.png", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
```

This does download something:

```
‰PNG

¾M&S»Á€>öÝÀKþé§ŸªCÂ²²²Ð½{wÕ5–-[†…*ï”‡7Þx½zõ¢C˜ž––L›6
555ŠÛŽ1þ³ºÂr­­­'­Å·Íê>ð^ùpAmèÀŽãœ.—«–@èEÀŒ±yJÛ)©éâàÔóÚÄÂ™ÄA]]¦NŠ¦æfÅ÷uÍ5Tò—+Ö­[‡¾òŠªúÕ×^CvŸ>gtò'­É·ý›œü¹QYñÇÝér¹þmöçpÁð^¯w€AJÛFâR€–tîÜ¹=Ï cä`íÚµX»v­âëÙív,X°€ªþa…$I¸ë®»T•¾ðÂqß}÷µÏàÛÖä:„ŠŠ
Šbª$€Ðÿ.
```

And while it starts with PNG this is not a valid png and also the original file is 39kb.
Do I have to send some additional headers or something? I would like to be able to download any specified file.

I used `vcpkg` to get libcurl:

```
curl:x64-windows                                   7.68.0
```

**EDIT:**

I have updated the code to reflect the answer of @Some programmer dude
I am now using `write` to output data to the file.
This has fixed for the example image I was using.

The problem I now have is with another image I am trying to download.

```
cr.downloadUrl("https://v217.mangabeast.com/manga/Onepunch-Man/0130-007.png", "image.png", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
```

The file `image.png` now contains the text:

```
error code: 1010
```

I can download this image by just using the command:

```
curl -O <url>
```

So I am not passing anything via the curl command so what do I need to pass in the libcurl??

Here is the output of the request:

```
 * STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x24781b66728; line 1605 (connection #-5000)
 * Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
 * STATE: CONNECT => WAITRESOLVE handle 0x24781b66728; line 1646 (connection #0)
 *   Trying 104.31.15.158:443...
 * TCP_NODELAY set
 * STATE: WAITRESOLVE => WAITCONNECT handle 0x24781b66728; line 1725 (connection #0)
 * Connected to v217.mangabeast.com (104.31.15.158) port 443 (#0)
 * STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x24781b66728; line 1781 (connection #0)
 * Marked for [keep alive]: HTTP default
 * schannel: SSL/TLS connection with v217.mangabeast.com port 443 (step 1/3)
 * schannel: checking server certificate revocation
 * schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 184 bytes...
 * schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 184 bytes
 * schannel: SSL/TLS connection with v217.mangabeast.com port 443 (step 2/3)
 * schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
 * STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x24781b66728; line 1796 (connection #0)
 * schannel: SSL/TLS connection with v217.mangabeast.com port 443 (step 2/3)
 * schannel: encrypted data got 2709
 * schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 2709 length 4096
 * schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 93 bytes...
 * schannel: SSL/TLS connection with v217.mangabeast.com port 443 (step 2/3)
 * schannel: encrypted data got 258
 * schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 258 length 4096
 * schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
 * schannel: SSL/TLS connection with v217.mangabeast.com port 443 (step 3/3)
 * schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
 * STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x24781b66728; line 1815 (connection #0)
> GET /manga/Onepunch-Man/0130-007.png HTTP/1.1
Host: v217.mangabeast.com
User-Agent: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*

 * STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x24781b66728; line 1870 (connection #0)
 * STATE: DO_DONE => PERFORM handle 0x24781b66728; line 1991 (connection #0)
 * schannel: client wants to read 16384 bytes
 * schannel: encdata_buffer resized 17408
 * schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 17408
 * schannel: encrypted data got 674
 * schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 674 length 17408
 * schannel: decrypted data length: 611
 * schannel: decrypted data added: 611
 * schannel: decrypted cached: offset 611 length 16384
 * schannel: encrypted data length: 34
 * schannel: encrypted cached: offset 34 length 17408
 * schannel: decrypted data length: 5
```

**EDIT2:**

I have now added some error checking and also a fail on error. I got the following:

```
ERROR: HTTP response code said error
The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
```

I don't understand how I get a `403` as using cURL via the command line gets me the image.

EDIT 3:

Just noticed that the user agent string has `User-Agent:`, after putting in a valid user agent I got the file!

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems, both stemming from the fact that you treat the data you receive as text.

The first problem is that you open the file in text-mode, which could mean that certain bytes are translated to other bytes (or even multiple other bytes). The most common such translation is the newline `'\n'` which on Windows would typically be translated to the two-character sequence `'\r'` and `'\n'`.

The second problem is that your `writeToFile` function assumes that the data is a null-terminated string, which it is not. The null-terminator used for strings is simply a byte with the value `0`. Arbitrary binary data (like a PNG image) will contain zero bytes in it. You need to write the data using the [`write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) function, passing the actual length in bytes of the data, which you get through the `size` argument to the cURL "write data" function callback.

To solve your first problem you need to open the file in binary mode by adding the `std::ios::bin` flag when opening the file. And the second problem can be solved by using the `write` function as already mentioned.

Comment: Hey, so I am passing `std::ios::out | std::ios::binary` as a 3rd parameter which I assumed would open it as binary, but I will use the `write` function. Thanks!

Comment: So you were correct about `write` function but it's not `size` I should be using but `nmemb` as `size` is always 1. And as noted the file was being opened in binary mode.
Thanks

Comment: @AntonioCS Ah right, I misremembered. `size` is the *element* size, which will always be `1` for a byte-oriented file. `nmemb` is the number of elements. So one should really use `size * nmemb` to get the correct size.

Comment: That will always be the value of `nmemb` as `size` is always 1. And `write` function did fix the issue for the image I was using as an example it seems to fail for others. I'll update my question.

Comment: @AntonioCS Size may be always 1 now but will it always be so in the future? The value is passed to your function so you should use it.

Comment: @ZanLynx I believe so, yes. It states in the documentation: `size is always 1. `